# The negative in "Sophie ate all her strawberries and so didn't Amelia"

Tags: american-english, negation

> New England speakers often use a negative form such as **so didn't** where others would use the positive, as in *Sophie ate all her strawberries and **so didn't** Amelia*. Since this usage may confuse a speaker who has not encountered it, it is best avoided in writing.

[-American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=so)

What linguistic process is this?

Comment: This is the [_So Don't I_ construction](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/so-dont-i).